# How do i use apache commons HttpPost to send a file and encode parameters for the request?

Tags: java, android, apache, http, post

I am currently programming an application that needs to send an http Post request to a server. The request needs to contain particular parameters which in an equivalent GET request would be encoded in the url. However, the body of the http Request needs to be correctly formatted xml which the server will parse. So, as I understand it, the file needs to be added to the request like so:

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url...");
    if (httpContent != null){
        InputStreamEntity httpStream = new InputStreamEntity(httpContent,-1);
        httpStream.setContentType("text/xml");
        httpStream.setChunked(true);

        post.setEntity(httpStream);
    }
```

And parameters need to be added as a name-value pair like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "12312"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sessionid", "234"));  
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

now, I am pretty sure that the httpPost can only have one entity set unless I am misunderstanding it. So, How can I set the parameters and still retain the xml as the http body?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `UrlEncodedFormEntity` - this is still a form entity, and won't give you the "GET request" equivalent that you're looking for.

Instead, just append your parameters on to the URL passed to the `HttpPost` constructor:

```
url...?userid=12312&sessionid=234
```

Comment: I need to have the parameters encoded in the http body like a regular POST request. Im not trying to construct a GET request. The problem is that i dont see how to encode the parameters and include the xml file.

Comment: @Mozoby - We need to better understand what is being required of the server you are submitting to.  If the above doesn't work, you may need to use the `UrlEncodedFormEntity`, and include all of the XML as a value with a given name.

Comment: This was correct, I needed to encode the parameters as GET parameters and put the XML in the POST body.